# Расстановка запятых в стихотворении Лермонтова "Силуэт"

Tags: учебное-задание, пунктуация

Пожалуйста, поясните расстановку запятых в стихотворении Лермонтова "Силуэт".

```
Силуэт

Есть у меня твой силуэт,
Мне мил его печальный цвет;
Висит он на груди моей,
И мрачен он, как сердце в ней.

В глазах нет жизни и огня,
Зато он вечно близ меня;
Он тень твоя, но я люблю,
Как тень блаженства, тень твою.
```

Comment: Легко хотите жить... Мы домашние задания за школьников не делаем. Будут вопросы - ответим, а делайте сами.

Answer (score 2):

А в чём проблема-то? Бессоюзное сложное предложение распадается на две части, между ними точка с запятой, тем более, что бессоюзное соединение частей сочетается с союзным.

`Есть у меня твой силуэт,` (запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложном).

`Мне мил его печальный цвет;` (точка с запятой разделяет на 2 части с разными мыслями: в первой части предложения о печали, во второй - о мрачности).

`Висит он на груди моей,` (отделяет простое в сложносочинённом).

`И мрачен он, как сердце в ней.` (сравнительный оборот)

**Во второй части то же самое.**